# Stripe's Checkout feature on mobile looks different

Tags: stripe-payments

Since Stripe's support takes a week to get back to me, I'm trying my luck here.

When you click on Stripe's simple Checkout feature it displays a beautiful "pop-up" (javascript?) to input credit card info. However when I view my site on my mobile phone (non-native) the pop-up does not show, instead it shows a plain unstyled page. Is this normal?

I've attached a screenshot of this plain mobile page. It would be great to know if this is normal default or if I'm doing something wrong. Also if in fact this is normal, how can I style this so that it looks consistent with the rest of my site?

Thank you in advance
Brian

[image]

Comment: What does the stylesheet look like when you inspect the code in mobile?

Comment: I just started getting this too; seems unexpected.

Comment: Ok so apparently it's because I'm currently using iOS version 5. Stripe support (yes I finally heard from them after 2 weeks) says anything version below 6 will show like this. The newer versions look fine.